# How to populate Ember.js's Select only by some objects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How to populate [Ember.js's Select](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html) only by objects with property `valid` equals `true`?

Array with data (JS):

```
 tickets: [
    {
        title: 'Pink',
        valid: true
    },
    {
        title: 'Blue',
        valid: false
    }
]
```

Select (HBS):

```
{{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding = ticket
    prompt = "Select ticket"
    optionLabelPath ="content.title"
}}
```

In this case I want to select shows only Pink on the options list.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can handle this, the easiest seems to filter the content before passing it into the ember select

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EGORAPI/1/edit

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  validItems: function(){
    return this.filterBy('valid', true);
  }.property('@each.valid')
});
```

Comment: For this solution, you would need to base the property off `@each.valid`, not just `@each` in order for it to update properly when data changes. Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EGORAPI/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Good point Luke, I was really just being lazy watching if new items were added (which might have been easier to watch length).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ember.computed.filterBy` to filter out the data.

```
validTicket: Ember.computed.filterBy('tickets','valid',true)
```

and in your hbs,

```
{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding = "validTicket"
prompt = "Select ticket"
optionLabelPath ="content.title" }}
```

Comment: Note: If you are using Ember 1.1, you need not to use `binding` to give content to `Ember.Select`. 
Refer [this PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3492)